# wrong datapoint attribute value in counter metrics

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I create a minimal reproducible project here: [github](https://github.com/oliverdding/otel-test)

Start server with fiber:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/gofiber/contrib/fiberzap"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2/middleware/favicon"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/attribute"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp/otlpmetric/otlpmetricgrpc"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/metric"
    sdkmetric "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/metric"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/metric/metricdata"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/resource"
    semconv "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/semconv/v1.18.0"
    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "go.uber.org/zap/zapcore"
)

var (
    logger *zap.Logger
)

func init() {
    var cfg zap.Config
    cfg = zap.NewDevelopmentConfig()

    // set time format
    cfg.EncoderConfig.EncodeTime = zapcore.TimeEncoderOfLayout(time.DateTime)
    // add color for console
    cfg.EncoderConfig.EncodeLevel = zapcore.CapitalColorLevelEncoder
    logger = zap.New(zapcore.NewCore(zapcore.NewConsoleEncoder(cfg.EncoderConfig), zapcore.NewMultiWriteSyncer(zapcore.AddSync(os.Stdout)), zapcore.DebugLevel))
}

func preferDeltaTemporalitySelector(kind sdkmetric.InstrumentKind) metricdata.Temporality {
    switch kind {
    case sdkmetric.InstrumentKindCounter,
        sdkmetric.InstrumentKindObservableCounter,
        sdkmetric.InstrumentKindHistogram:
        return metricdata.DeltaTemporality
    default:
        return metricdata.CumulativeTemporality
    }
}

func initProvider(ctx context.Context) func() {
    res, err := resource.New(ctx,
        resource.WithFromEnv(),
        resource.WithProcess(),
        resource.WithTelemetrySDK(),
        resource.WithHost(),
        resource.WithAttributes(
            semconv.ServiceName("server"),
            semconv.ServiceNamespace("demo"),
            semconv.ServiceVersion("0.1.0"),
        ),
    )
    if err != nil {
        logger.Fatal("failed to create resource", zap.Error(err))
    }

    otelAgentAddr, ok := os.LookupEnv("OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT")
    if !ok {
        otelAgentAddr = "127.0.0.1:4317"
    }
    metricExp, err := otlpmetricgrpc.New(
        ctx,
        otlpmetricgrpc.WithInsecure(),
        otlpmetricgrpc.WithEndpoint(otelAgentAddr),
        otlpmetricgrpc.WithCompressor("gzip"),
        otlpmetricgrpc.WithTemporalitySelector(preferDeltaTemporalitySelector),
    )

    meterProvider := sdkmetric.NewMeterProvider(
        sdkmetric.WithResource(res),
        sdkmetric.WithReader(
            sdkmetric.NewPeriodicReader(
                metricExp,
                sdkmetric.WithInterval(2*time.Second),
            ),
        ),
    )
    otel.SetMeterProvider(meterProvider)

    return func() {
        cxt, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second)
        defer cancel()
        // pushes any last exports to the receiver
        if err := meterProvider.Shutdown(cxt); err != nil {
            otel.Handle(err)
        }
    }
}

var (
    meter metric.Meter
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    otelShutdownHook := initProvider(ctx)
    defer otelShutdownHook()

    meter = otel.Meter("demo-server")

    app := fiber.New(fiber.Config{
        AppName:           "demo-server",
        CaseSensitive:     true,
        DisableKeepalive:  true,
        EnablePrintRoutes: true,
    })
    app.Use(favicon.New())
    app.Use(fiberzap.New(fiberzap.Config{
        Logger:   logger,
        SkipURIs: []string{"/favicon.ico"},
        Fields:   []string{"time", "method", "path", "status", "respHeader:X-Request-ID", "ip", "port", "ua", "latency"},
        Levels:   []zapcore.Level{zapcore.WarnLevel},
    }))

    requestCount, _ := meter.Int64Counter(
        "demo_server/request_counts",
        metric.WithDescription("The number of requests received"),
    )

    app.Get("/hello/:app_id", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        appID := c.Params("app_id")

        logger.Info("hello", zap.String("app_id", appID))

        requestCount.Add(c.UserContext(), 1, metric.WithAttributes(attribute.String("interface", "hello"), attribute.String("app_id", appID)))

        return nil
    })

    app.Get("/bye/:app_id", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        appID := c.Params("app_id")

        logger.Info("bye", zap.String("app_id", appID))

        requestCount.Add(c.UserContext(), 1, metric.WithAttributes(attribute.String("interface", "bye"), attribute.String("app_id", appID)))

        return nil
    })

    app.Listen("0.0.0.0:2333")
}
```

Then send HTTP request: `curl http://127.0.0.1:2333/hello/1024`. We can see the server get the app_id = 1024 properly, but it's SDK report wrong value like 'n.i' to the OpenTelemetry collector. That's pretty strange.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to fix this, thanks in advance!